# How to retrieve all objects in model database and send it through ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

Hello I've been having trouble passing my data from views.py (objects.all) to my ajax. What I wanted to do is for every object in the query set, I'll append its details in a div in my html. I tried serializing it but I'm having trouble on how to loop through the serialized JSON. Any suggestions? Pls help.

**jQuery**

```
function getOffers(key){
        dict = {
            'key':key// pk value of post sent to retrieve offers to it
        };
        key = "pk";//I actually dont know what to put here
        generateCSRFToken();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/retrieve_offers/",
            method: "POST",
            data : JSON.stringify(dict),
            success: function(data){
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(data);

                //HOW TO LOOP THROUGH THE DATA AND GET EACH PK
            },
            error: function(){
            }

        })
    }
```

**views.py**

```
def retrieve_offers(request):
    dict = json.loads(request.body)
    post_key = Post.objects.get(pk=dict["key"])
    offers = Offer.objects.filter(post_id=post_key)

    data = serializers.serialize('json',offers)

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(data),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    date_submitted = models.DateField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    author = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(to=Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    trade_item = models.FileField(null=True,blank=True)
    trade_item_name = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=100)
    receive_item = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    receive_item_name = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk) + " by " + (self.author.username)

    @staticmethod
    def create(date_submitted, description, author, category):
        post = Post()
        post.date_submitted = date_submitted
        post.description = description
        post.author = author
        post.category = category
        return post

class Offer(models.Model):
    date_submitted = models.DateField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    author = models.ForeignKey(to=User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_id = models.ForeignKey(to=Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    item_name = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=100)
```

**console.log(data)** 
[here is the console.log result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH2YB.png)

**sample result of serialized JSON**

```
'[{"model": "bartr.offer", "pk": 26, "fields": {"date_submitted": "2017-03-30", "description": "asdasd", "author": 38, "post_id": 23, "image": "pexels-photo-167810_7vvcPK4.jpeg", "item_name": "something"}}]'
```

Comment: when you wish to send json using $.ajax you need to set appropriate contentType. Default is not application/json

Comment: It kinda works fine for me. My only problem is how to loop through the returned serialized JSON

Comment: Show sample of actual data returned (not an image). In image it is array...iterate that array using any array looping method you want

Comment: right now I am using this method but its quite not working. Its showing me a different value out of nowhere not even close to the pk  Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key){

                    $("#offercontainer").html(
                        "<p>" + key + "</p>"
                    )

                });

Comment: you don't use `Object.keys()` to iterate array and `html()` will replace the innerHTML every iteration. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl I added an edit showing the serialized JSON. Sorry I havent done anything like this before and the html() is just for testing purposes if it will work. Can you give me any suggestions to access the post id of each for example?

Comment: I tried to console.log(data[0].fields.author) it shows me 51 instead of 38

Comment: try `data.forEach(function(item){ console.log(item.fields.author);})`

Comment: this is what I needed thank you! I was using the complicated Objects.keys() but I didnt know simple loops would work. Thank you so much

Comment: Yes...it is an array of objects, not an object literal